# asp.net lock page method until action finished

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net page that execute some update to db. The updates takes 2-3 seconds, all these hapends in a method that first read data from db and do some updates. When the page request are less then 2 sec for these action, the db read code, read the same state of records in db, and all update actions of asp.net page requests updates the same records.

How i can prevent these, that the newest request wait untill the oldest finish their execution?

Any ideas?

Comment: To synchronize different pages (or any clients) accessing the same data you need to use database locks. What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL 2008, an use ADO.NET Dataset to read data and update.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/798234/284240

Comment: Can these be done in source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to block access to a particular set of methods until the process has been completed.

Easy enough... create a static method and implement a lock().  You can get real fancy with share locks, upgrades to read/write locks, etc... but the basic principal is that you lock your critical sections of shared code so other users cannot enter those sections.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.71).aspx

The lock keyword marks a statement block as a critical section by obtaining the mutual-exclusion lock for a given object, executing a statement, and then releasing the lock.

```
static object lockObject = new Object();
static bool inProgress = false;

static void MyProcess()
{
  if(inProgress) return;

  lock(lockObject)
  {
    try{
      inProgress = true;
      // critical code here
    }
    finally
    {
      inProgress = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the appropriate isolation level and database locks: these would ensure that any client (any transaction to be precise) is correctly handled and data integrity is presereved (check [isolation levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189542.aspx)).

I'd suggest using READ COMMITTED which ensures that you never read uncommitted data and transactions are queued during updates to the same record.