# Force a query timeout in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm looking for the oracle equivalent for `WAITFOR DELAY` in [MsSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798192/forcing-a-query-timeout-in-sql-server) so I can test what happens when I get a timeout in my scripts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Silly, typing this question gave me the perfect google query which lead met to this answer:

```
BEGIN
    dbms_lock.sleep(5);
END;
```