# How to handle database transaction failures in ColdFusion?

Tags: ms-access, coldfusion

I am getting a database time out exception, but not consistently. Some times it executes and some times it fails. I would like to write a log file on database failure. My query is enclosed with `CFTRANSACTION`.

So my question is how can I detect the TRANSACTION failure so that I can write a log? Also, where do I put try/catch block; inside the `CFTRANSACTION` or put the `CFTRANSACTION` inside the try/catch block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be a starting point.  Here is a link to simulate a long running query in SQL Server: [Forcing a query timeout in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798192/forcing-a-query-timeout-in-sql-server/)

```
<cftransaction>

    <cftry>
        <cfquery datasource="mydatasource" timeout="1">
            <!--- problem query --->
        </cfquery>

        <cfcatch type="Database">
        <!--- write to log --->
            <cftransaction action="rollback" />
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>

</cftransaction>
```