# Force SQL Server to respond slowly in order to test client application response to timeout

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to somehow force Microsoft SQL Server to slow down certain or all queries so that we can test the client application on how it acts when the SQL queries run for extended time? For example, by seriously limiting its I/O or CPU to 1%.

Unfortunately it is not possible to modify the data in the database to add more rows.

I tried [Forcing a query timeout in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798192/forcing-a-query-timeout-in-sql-server) but unfortunately the client application issues `SELECT WITH (NOLOCK)` so it ignores any locks we create.

Comment: Whenever I want to mess with SQL in the performance department I just cross join a decent sized table against itself a bunch of times. You end up with a resultset of R^(N+1) where R is the number of rows in the table and N is the number of times you cross join. Take a table with 1000 rows in it and Cross Join two times and you end up with a billion rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To force query timeout error for `SELECT ... FROM MySchema.MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)` queries:**

`SELECT ... FROM MySchema.MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)` still requires `Sch-S` lock. According to [Lock Compatibility (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), `Sch-S` lock has a conflict with `Sch-M` lock.

1) So, create a new query in SSMS and execute the next script:

```
BEGIN TRAN

ALTER TABLE MySchema.MyTable
ADD DummyCol INT NULL DEFAULT 0 -- It requires Sch-M lock

--ROLLBACK
```

2) Execute the queries (from client app. or from another SSMS query) with `NOLOCK` table hint:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    MySchema.MyTable d WITH(NOLOCK) -- It requires Sch-S lock
```

3) Now, you have to wait.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` requires `Sch-M` lock. T

Comment: now this is interesting :) first thing tomorrow will check it out and hopefully it will do what we need..

Comment: Don't try this on a production server. And, of course, don't forget to `ROLLBACK` first transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WAITFOR DELAY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx) to, well, make the code wait if you use stored procedures.

Controlling CPU requires [Resource Governer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx), but I've not used it. IIRC, it requires Enterprise edition

Comment: I cannot modify the client application to change those queries.

Comment: @Knaģis: what can you change?

Comment: SQL Server settings, probably some database setting changes as long as I can reverse them.